# Regex format to match a number string

Tags: regular-expression

I want to match a string, basically a regex format where in I want to match numbers from 0-255 & 257 above. That means except 256 every number.

Can someone help with the regex format for the same ?

Comment: it will depend on which tool you are using as well... regex features vary a lot between tools... also add some sample input and expected output... see http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html for getting started

Comment: A regex is not the right tool for this task. Care to give some context on the problem? If so, edit the question.  Somebody might be able to suggest another method.

Comment: (1) What have you tried?  (2) What’s the deal with leading zeroes?

Comment: How about 0x100, 2.56e+2, -256, 0400? Note that in a `256` string there are 5 numbers (2, 5, 6, 25, 56) that are not 256.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, these numbers are all integers. The idea is to match and display entries that contain such numbers but 256, preceeded or not by leading zeros.

**Should your numbers be each on a single line**:

```
grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"
```

(`grep -v` excludes lines that match instead of including them)

Ouput:

```
$ echo "12" | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"
12

$ echo "2567" | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"
2567

$ echo "256" | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"

$ echo "0256" | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"

$ echo "something" | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"
```

**Should you be using another separator:**

You can for example preprocess your inputs using `sed` to make them compatible with the `grep` commands above. Here with a coma-delimitated input where each coma is replaced by a line-feed (`\n`):

```
sed -r 's/,/\n/g'
```

Output:

```
$ echo "2567,255,256,12,something,05,0256" | sed -r 's/,/\n/g' | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"
2567
255
12
05
```

**And finally, should your numbers be mixed with other random characters:**

In that case, an extra step allows removing all non-numerical characters:

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

Output:

```
$ echo "2567,255,256,mama256a,papa1812b,something,05,0256" | sed -r 's/,/\n/g' | sed -r 's/[^0-9]//g' | grep "^[0-9][0-9]*$" | grep -v "^0*256$"
2567
255
1812
05
```